# How do I connect to a LibreOfficeBase-database?

Tags: c#, database, radix

I hope this isn't a repost but I couldn't find an answer yet. 
How can I connect to a LibreOfficeBase-database in C#? I don't have MS Access, that's why I only have Libre. So far, this is what I wrote:

```
private void add_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection();
    OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand();
    OleDbDataReader reader;

    con.ConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;" +  
    "Data Source=C:\\Users\\user\\Desktop\\data.odb;";

    cmd.Connection = con;
    cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO data(name, age)" +
        "VALUES('" + FamilyName.Text + "', '" + Age.Text +"')";
    try
    {
        con.Open();
        reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        reader.Close();
        con.Close();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
    }
}
```

My database is called data.odb and of course it isn't working, because this method is for .accdb files. What do I do for .odb files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*odb* is openoffice database. There is a MySQL connector present for working with odb file see here https://wiki.openoffice.org/wiki/Database/Drivers/MySQL_Native/1.0.

Also you might want to go through OpenOffice documentation https://wiki.openoffice.org/wiki/Database#Developer which says how to connect to MS Access https://wiki.openoffice.org/wiki/Connecting_to_Microsoft_Access